# Markov Inequality question confusion bound problem

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, markov-chains, upper-lower-bounds

"If a fair die is rolled 200 times, count the number of 1’s. Give an upper bound for the probability that the count of 1’s stays below 8. "
So here for Markov inequality, 
P(X>=8)<=E[X]/8. 
So here, E[X]=200*(1/6). 
So, P(X>=8) <=200/(8*6) <= 4.1666.
Markov gives lower bound.
So for upper bound, 
1-4.166= -3.166
Is the answer correct? How can the probability get less than 0?

Comment: Use Markov's inequality for $Y=$ number of not-ones.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The actual figure seems to be about $0.00000000517$ -in R `pbinom(7,200,1/6)` - so the Markov bound is extremely loose.  A Chebyshev bound would not be so absurd but would still be very loose

Answer (score 1):

$P(X\le 8)=P(Y\ge 192)\le E[Y]/192$

Now, $E[Y]=200\times 5/6=166.666$ and the above inequality gives the estimate
$$
P(X\le 8)\le 0.86805...
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I have been stuck with this problem for days. Do you know any online resources where I can find similar problems?

Comment: Glad to help. No idea where you can find these things online, sorry about that.

Comment: Could you help me finding Chebychef, Hoeﬀding and Chernoff bound of the above math? For Chebyshef I need to find the variance. But I am not able to find that. For Hoefding, I need "dn" but what is "dn" here? For Chernoff I need the value "c". What is c here?

Comment: For Chebyshev, observe that $Y$ is a binomial variable with probability of success $p=5/6$ and $N=200$ (the number of trials). Therefore the variance is $Np(1-p)=27.777$. For Hoeffding, you have a sum of Bernoulli variables.

Comment: Thanks man. With your help, I was able to calculate the chebyshev bound to 0.02. 
Could you please tell me,  "For Hoeffding, you have a sum of Bernoulli variables" what do you mean by that? Also, how can I calculate chernoff?

Comment: The variable $Y$ is a sum of 200 Bernoulli variables $X_1, . . . , X_{200}$ with parameter $p=5/6$. According to Hoeffding’s inequality, $P(|\bar X_{200} −5/6|>ε)\le 2e^{−400\epsilon^2}$.Or $P(|\sum X_i −166.66|>200ε)\le 2e^{−400\epsilon^2}$. Now choose $\epsilon$.

Comment: What is the form of Chernov's inequality you have in mind?

Comment: Multiplicative may be. I am not sure.